# In R I overrode a function, how do I get it back?

Tags: r

I did something silly in an R session. I wrote

> print = FALSE

Now I can't print things!

> print
>   [1] FALSE

How do I get it back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The irony here is that you did NOT overwrite it. You created a data object named "print" and when you typed `print` at the console, the eval-print loop took over and returned it. Had you tested for the behavior of print correctly by typing `print("something")` or `print(42)` you would have seen that the interpreter was still able to find the `print.default` function in the base NAMESPACE. Defining data objects with the same names as existing functions is bad practice, not because they overwrite in the R interpreter, but because they overwrite in minds of users. The interpreter determines your intent (well, it determines what it will do anyway) by seeing whether there is a open-parenthesis which signifies a function call. If the letters p-r-i-n-t are followed by "(" then the interpreter looks at the class of the argument and dispatches the appropriate print method.

Answer (score 11):

`rm` will not remove base objects, so you can just run:

```
rm(print)
```

Interestingly, you *can* print things:

```
> print <- FALSE
> print
[1] FALSE
> print("hi")
[1] "hi"
> rm(print)
> print("hi")
[1] "hi"
> print
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("print")
<bytecode: 0x2a3a148>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Answer (score 3):

Take it back from the namespace

```
print = base::print
```

Comment: This makes an unnecessary copy of `base::print` in the global environment. Better to just delete the `print` object you created (as @gsk suggested in his answer).

Comment: It was never in the base:NAMESPACE. It takes more programming violence than that to mess with the base functions.