# Why does this work? Creating a logical with same name as base function still allows the function to be used

Tags: r

I ran across an oddity here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11084038/636656

It appears that assigning to a name that is the same as a base function still allows you to use the base function:

```
> print <- FALSE
> print
[1] FALSE
> print("hi")
[1] "hi"
> 
> sum <- FALSE
> sum(1:10)
[1] 55
> sum
[1] FALSE
```

By contrast, assigning a function to the same name as a base function does not produce the same behavior:

```
> sum <- function(x) x^2
> sum(1:10)
 [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
> sum
function(x) x^2
```

I'm aware that these sit in different namespaces, but I'm curious about two things:

1. **Why**: Is this a failsafe to avoid difficult-to-recover-from behavior (e.g. if you overwrite `rm`)?  What is the principle that predicts this behavior?
2. **How**: Are there different lookup routines for functions and logicals by namespace?

Comment: It's because you haven't overwritten the function. You've simply declared a new variable called `print`. This is explained in the answers in this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6135868/602276

Comment: @Andrie I'll rewrite to be more careful with my terminology.  One sec.

Comment: See my answer to the question you just got 3 upvotes for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When evaluating a call to `print()`, R searches (along its ordinary search path) for a **function** with the name `print`. Your object `print <- TRUE` has the right name, but isn't a function, so the search shoots right past to the the first function having the right name.

Here's John Chambers' explanation, from "Chapter 13: How R works" in [Software for Data Analysis: Programming with R](http://www.springer.com/statistics/computanional+statistics/book/978-0-387-75935-7).

> The evaluation of the function call begins by looking for a function corresponding to the name. The rules for "looking for" are the same as the general rules for evaluating names mentioned above, except that the evaluator silently ignores any object found that is not a function, allowing local non-function objects with the same name as non-local functions, a concession motivated by people's tendency to assign objects names such as "c".

(I especially like that last bit about this being "a concession motivated by people's tendency to ..." ;)

---

Since you're interested in this, it's also worth having a look at `match.fun()`, which is designed to "extract the desired function object while avoiding undesired matching to objects of other types". It includes the following line, which nicely illustrates the strategy used by both and the evaluator:

```
FUN <- get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir)
```

Comment: @gsk3 -- If you haven't yet seen that book, I'd definitely recommend it. On another note, I think that by the time `print(...)` has been passed through the **parser**, that whole construct has been identified as a call expression. That is how the **evaluator** knows it should carry out a 'specialized' symbol lookup for `print`.  (Since I don't really understand the division of labor between parser and evaluator, though, that part is kind of hand-wavy, so I left it out of the answer.)

Comment: I was pretty sure I'd seen this in Chambers but the book was in my other office.  Nice find, thanks.

Comment: Following up to my comment above, I guess this indicates that it's the **parser** that identifies that construct as a call: `class(parse(text="PRINT('hi')")[[1]])`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I have the yellow book ("S Programming") but it's apparently very much not the same thing.  I'll try to pick up that one soon.